# Is uploading an image from local HD to remote AMFPHP method possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, amfphp

Can any AMFPHP experts tell me if it's possible to upload a file I select from my local HD using `FileReference` to an AMFPHP method?

I must target FP9, though I know FP10 has a `FileReference.data` method.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is. You can pass the content of your FileReference straight to a php script.

Have a look at the [samples](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/samples/Programming_ActionScript3.0_samples.zip) that come with Programming Flash CS3.

Here is some of that sample code if it helps. I didn't write this, Adobe did.

```
package com.example.programmingas3.fileio {
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    import fl.controls.Button;
    import fl.controls.ProgressBar;

    public class FileUpload {
        // Hard-code the URL of the remote upload script.
        private const UPLOAD_URL:String = "http://www.yourdomain.com/upload_script.cfm";
        private var fr:FileReference;
        // Define reference to the upload ProgressBar component.
        private var pb:ProgressBar;
        // Define reference to the "Cancel" button which will immediately stop the upload in progress.
        private var btn:Button;

        public function FileUpload() {
        }

        /**
         * Set references to the components, and add listeners for the SELECT,
         * OPEN, PROGRESS, and COMPLETE events.
         */
        public function init(pb:ProgressBar, btn:Button):void {
            // Set up the references to the progress bar and cancel button, which are passed from the calling script.
            this.pb = pb;
            this.btn = btn;

            fr = new FileReference();
            fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
            fr.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
            fr.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
            fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        }

        /**
         * Immediately cancel the upload in progress and disable the cancel button.
         */
        public function cancelUpload(e:MouseEvent):void {
            fr.cancel();
//            pb.label = "UPLOAD CANCELLED";
            btn.enabled = false;
        }

        /**
         * Launch the browse dialog box which allows the user to select a file to upload to the server.
         */
        public function startUpload(e:MouseEvent):void {
            fr.browse();
        }

        /**
         * Begin uploading the file specified in the UPLOAD_URL constant.
         */
        private function selectHandler(event:Event):void {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
            request.url = UPLOAD_URL;
            fr.upload(request);
        }

        /**
         * When the OPEN event has dispatched, change the progress bar's label 
         * and enable the "Cancel" button, which allows the user to abort the 
         * upload operation.
         */
        private function openHandler(event:Event):void {
//            pb.label = "UPLOADING";
            btn.enabled = true;
        }

        /**
         * While the file is uploading, update the progress bar's status and label.
         */
        private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
//            pb.label = "UPLOADING %3%%";
            pb.setProgress(event.bytesLoaded, event.bytesTotal);
        }

        /**
         * Once the upload has completed, change the progress bar's label and 
         * disable the "Cancel" button since the upload is already completed.
         */
        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
//            pb.label = "UPLOADING COMPLETE";
            pb.setProgress(0, 100);
            btn.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```